# VPN debugging / deep t-shoot questions

Tags: cisco, vpn

We have a client that has many 3rd party connections on a daily basis being stood up.  A frequent problem is that the 3rd party will miscommunicate about their P1/P2 settings and during turn-up - lie about what they have configured, leaving us to search around for the right settings by trying different transform-sets / encryption etc etc until we get the right combination at which point they 'realize' the difference in configuration.

Is there a way through debugging to know definitively what is configured on the other end as far as P1/P2 settings / SA's?  I have to figure since the boxes must negotiate these SA's there is some way to debug and see this.

We're looking for the ability to say: "We can see you have X Y Z configured on your P1 (or P2) - and that doesn't match what you submitted in the change documentation of A B C".

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unless things have changed, Cisco's `debug` output is intentionally cryptic to "protect" the transaction. Every time I've had to debug this crap, I've used wireshark to see the entire packet. From there, it's easy to see what single-freakin'-bit is different. (by "easy" I mean a tedious task of comparing every single bit in both directions to find the one that isn't matching.)